# Google map with postal code and custom marker image

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm currently using the Google Map's staticmap with a postal code and the standard red marker. I would like to use a custom png image instead of the red marker.

I've tried adding the url of the image with the marker parameter in the url but it gives an error in the map.

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=v302t8&zoom=9&size=460x150&maptype=roadmap&key=APIKEY&markers=color:red%7Cv302t8" alt="">
```

I'd like to be able to use this method as opposed to the geocoding method as they the number of queries is limited.

Comment: running the above with a valid postcode ( which is what I believe `v302t8` is supposed to be ) works ok - but using the above causes the map error... verify the actual postcode is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the `center` location `v302t8` ( source of the error? ) is or the final `%7Cv302t8` in the map url so I modified the above as you can see below. The map loads OK and displays a custom marker image centred upon the `"Tower of London"`

The chosen image should be 64px x 64px or less.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.507336, -0.074968&zoom=15&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&key=<APIKEY>&markers=icon:http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/af/afeef641914e77b0950eb8b8317bfbf080b69ace_medium.jpg|51.507336, -0.074968
```

[image: Static map - centred on City of London]

Update:
Using a `png` file also works - again bearing in mind the max dimensions of the marker image

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.507336, -0.074968&zoom=15&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&key=<APIKEY>&markers=icon:https://cartoon.aminoapps.com/static/bower/emojify.js/images/emoji/skull.png|51.507336, -0.074968
```

[image: Static map with transparent PNG image as marker]

Comment: Thanks for this, jpg images work but it doesn't seem to support png files. Is there a way to use a png with a transparent background?

Comment: It works perfectly well with PNG files too - be aware of the size of the images though.. see an update above

Comment: I am using a 64x64 24-bit png with 80% opactity/transparency but it doesn't show up. Does the png image file need ot be hosted on a cdn?

Comment: you should be able to use the FULL url if it is on YOUR website - it cannot be on your development machine - the path to the image must be a fully qualified URL afaik

Comment: I've out the full url including the https://domain+path but no luck. What I am really trying do is adding a map circle with an see through opacity to show an approximate location. I see google has this but how can I add this to my integration: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

Comment: you need to add your actual code and not little bits that mislead the reader ~ what you are trying to do is significantly different to the initial question

Comment: Yes I am just trying to add a map circle. At first I thought the image was the only way then found the google javascript way. Here's the code I have with the radius.png file. 

<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=T5A 0A2&zoom=9&size=460x165&maptype=roadmap&key=APIKEY&markers=icon:https://www.bargaincity.ca/img/radius.png|T5A 0A2" alt="" class="img-responsive">

Comment: use the full URL including protocol... ie: `https://bargaincity.ca/img/radius.png`

Comment: Oh I am already using the full url, this comment form stripped out the https portion

Comment: Ok I got it figured out, the png image shows up when it's non-ssl. When I add the "s" on the end of https, it doesn't work.